# android title won't show in toolbar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, toolbar, android-actionbar-compat, android-toolbar

I have an xml that I use with so many activities with fragments file but my problem is that I can't display the text I want in the toolbar, I use that xml that way because I have a navigation drawer and I needed to handle somethings so I had to do it that way.

my xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/frame_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".StatusActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        style="@style/ToolBarStyle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:minHeight="@dimen/abc_action_bar_default_height_material" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

One of my activities:

```
public class GroupChatActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_base_layout);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
         setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
         getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

         ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
         actionBar.setTitle("Groups history");

        Aniways.init(this);

        if(savedInstanceState == null)
        {
            FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();

            Fragment fragment = GroupChatFragment.newInstance(getIntent().getIntExtra("uid", 0));
            manager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();
        }
    }
}
```

as you can see I try to set title to the action bar but it doesn't work.

Comment: Try calling `getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true)` then `toolbar.setTitle(title)`

Comment: @NikolaDespotoski Tried that, it doesn't work.

Comment: Try calling (in kotlin) supportActionBar?.title = Html.fromHtml("<font color=\"black\">Toolbar title</font>")

Answer (score 51, accepted):

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
```

Comment: For me it works without this on Android 5.1.1 i.e. with only getSupportActionBar().setTitle the title inside the toolbar is set, but if I try to set the title directly from the toolbar reference it doesn't, only through getSupportActionBar()

Answer (score 23):

Setting,

```
app:title="@string/my_title"
```

within the declaration of the the android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar, hard codes the title in the toolbar.

To set the title programatically,

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
toolbar.setTitle("my title");
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

in your activity class.

Comment: Why the hell does `android:title` not throw some kind of error?!

Answer (score 8):

Try this .. this method works for me..!! hope it may help somebody..!!

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar  
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"  
 android:id="@+id/my_awesome_toolbar"  
 android:layout_width="match_parent"  
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
 android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"  
 android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"  
 app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" >  

<TextView  
   android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"  
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
   android:layout_gravity="center"  
   android:singleLine="true"  
   android:text="Toolbar Title"  
   android:textColor="@android:color/white"  
   android:textSize="18sp"  
   android:textStyle="bold" />  

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

**EDIT**

You can also use this.

```
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
if (getSupportActionBar() != null)
      getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Toolbar title");
```

Comment: by doing this seems like getSupportActionBar() functionality is cut short

Comment: yes, but not getSupportActionBar() not works for me, for some worse cases i use this,..

Answer (score 3):

I spent about a day looking for the cause of the issue. Neither `supportActionBar?.title = "SomeTitle"` nor `supportActionBar?.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true)` did not work, nor hacks with custom toolbars from answers here looked good.

My activity is using `CollapsingToolbarLayout` but not displaying any title, nor `label` from manifest, nor dynamically set one. But the sample `ScrollingActivity` (New - Activity - ...) *displayed the title.*

Finally I set up a sample project, copied `MyActivity` and `ScrollingActivity` and looked through the diff.

*`layout_height` both of the `AppBarLayout` and `CollapsingToolbarLayout` **must** be set to `match_parent` or fixed size.* Thats all. See working code below.

```
<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/app_bar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="180dp"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
            >

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
                app:toolbarId="@id/toolbar"
                app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
                >

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                    app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                    />

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
```

Comment: You can achieve the same by setting app:titleEnabled="false" on the CollapsingToolbarLayout

Answer (score 1):

Try `toolbar.setTitle('Groups history');`

Comment: "Goals History" you should be passing arguments with double quotes

Answer (score 1):

`getActionBar().setTitle("Groups History");`

or if you are using `AppCompat` libraries;

`getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Groups History");`

Answer (score 1):

I did a custom action bar.

Layout iguepardos_action_bar.xml with this code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/toolbar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/blanco"
android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize">

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:text="Toolbar Title"
    android:textColor="@color/naranja"
    android:textSize="18sp" />

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

In my Class extended AppCompatActivity I had this:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
.... 
....

getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true); // is for specify use custom bar 
getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.iguepardos_action_bar);  // my custom layout
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true); // Button for come back

View mCustomView = getSupportActionBar().getCustomView(); // Set the view
TextView TitleToolBar = (TextView) mCustomView.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_title); // find title control
TitleToolBar.setText("The Title Show"); // Set the Title

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I actually had to get the toolbar_title to set the text into each different activity:

```
    toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    toolbarTitle = findViewById(R.id.toolbar_title);   //<----- here
    toolbarTitle.setText(getString(R.string.my_activity_toolbar_title));
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

if your title color is white and the toolbar is also white, you will not differentiate it. So try to change the toolbar color

Answer (score 0):

Given below code worked me:

```
 Toolbar myToolBar = findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
 setSupportActionBar(myToolBar);
 getSupportActionBar().setTitle(getString(R.string.toolbar_title_note));
```

First I tried with `getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);` and then without it. It worked for both of the cases.

These are gradle settings for my project:

```
minSdkVersion 16
targetSdkVersion 30
compileSdkVersion 30
buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"
```