# Android Studio 1.5 create new activity with actionbar collapsed

Tags: android-studio, android-actionbar

Just updated my android studio today to 1.5.1 and decide to create new project. I created new `Blank Activity`, the one with floating action bar inside it. I didn't even touch the code, then hit run on my device (asus zenfone 4).

[image: actionbar]

Then I realize my actionbar didn't work well. It is collapsed. Is this a bug with my device? Or am I missing some editing my style.xml?

This is my styles.xml, it is fresh from the android studio's oven.

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>

    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

</resources>
```

And this is my activity declaration on manifest

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

and this is actually what android studio give me as onCreate method

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                .setAction("Action", null).show();
    }
});
```

Comment: as you wish, @SpiderMan

Comment: `android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">`                                                                                                 change this to                                                                                                    `android:theme="@style/AppTheme">`

Comment: are you using the toolbar here .? can you please post your java code as well which might help us to understand your problem clearly.

Comment: actually, this is what android studio give me as their default new applications. Please show my update for toolbar support. @RaguSwaminathan

Comment: refer this link to setup toolbar for your activity http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27643248/android-title-wont-show-in-toolbar/33531391#33531391

Answer (score 0):

if you wish not to show actionBar in next activity in your NextActivity.java in onCreate add this code:

```
 android.support.v7.app.ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
 actionBar.hide();
```

this way you don't risk any typo errors in xml which could make that your app crashes