# How to set custom toolbar background in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-toolbar, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, android-appbarlayout

Hey guys I am using custom toolbar in my project. When I try to scroll view it goes behind the toolbar and see all item. I made a short [video](https://youtu.be/70cBFU69BYI) please have a look.

**toolbar.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:focusable="true">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        app:elevation="0dp"
        tools:layout_height="170dp">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsingToolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed|snap">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView
                android:id="@+id/searchView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:theme="@style/SearchViewTheme"
                app:closeIcon="@drawable/ic_cancel"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:searchIcon="@drawable/ic_search" />

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/consultationsToolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:theme="@style/ActionBarTheme">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/title"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/account_details" />

            </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/nested_scroll_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

       /// more item

    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I tried to put white background on toolbar, it solve the problem when scroll but another occur. When my searchview collapse its invisible. I think it's goes behind white background. I also made a [short video](https://youtu.be/-3mQrnXUA-8) for that.

```
           <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/consultationsToolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                android:background="@color/white"
                app:theme="@style/ActionBarTheme">
```

**styles.xml**

```
<style name="ActionBarTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/aqua</item>
        <item name="color">@color/aqua</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBarStyle</item>
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBarStyle</item>
        <item name="actionMenuTextAppearance">@style/MenuItemTextAppearance</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/aqua</item>
</style>
```

Any idea How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Try [this](https://pastebin.com/Usp76vs2) out

Comment: I tried this but nothing works. The result is same.

Comment: You added ` app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"` in `toolbar` which one back goes inside status bar.

Comment: @Zain any update for this?

Comment: I tried it; but as there are customizable code here that could be the reason; I will provide you with a similar behavior that I did before.

Comment: yeah sure, no problem

Comment: [HYG](https://pastebin.pl/view/32b9eed4)